# How to read the values in a dictionary of a list

Tags: python

I have the list below that looks like this

```
my_test_data = []
```

when I print my_test_data I get the result below

```
[
    {
        'tnType': None, 
        'tnCode': None, 
        'postedDt': None, 
        'amt': None, 'tranDesc1': None
    }
]
```

This to me looks like a dictionary in a list

I tried printing like this

```
for key, val in my_test_data.items():
    print(key, val)
```

I got an error message like this : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

I want to be able to read the value on every row and store that value in another list.

How can I read this one by one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused about here, but I suppose I have the benefit of experience. The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is: `my_test_data` is a `list`, which doesn't have an `items` attribute. It's actually `dict` objects that have `items`. Did you forget to loop over `my_test_data`, or did you forget to select the first item (`my_test_data[0]`)? Or something else, like you expected the attribute access to be applied to all dicts inside the list? You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: BTW, what interpreter are you using that prints like that? IPython also does pretty-printing, but in a different format. And I've never seen two keys printed on the same row while all other keys get their own row.

Comment: What should the other list look like at the end? It's hard to answer without knowing quite what you want. For reference, see [mre]. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: The other list should just store the values retrievec from  each row. Example secondList = ['None', 'None', 'None']

Comment: Why only three of them? Why are they strings? btw please [edit] to add that info.

Comment: Adding 3 was just an example to show you what it will look like. The count will match what is in the data.

Comment: Gotcha. Please write out *exactly* what you want to make it clear.

Comment: I need only the values stored in another list and this line of code will do it for me. I just tested it.  for key, val in allTransactions[0].items():
    print(val)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an internal object inside a list, you can solve the problem with a simple approach.

You can access the list item at index 0 easily:

```
for key, val in my_test_data[0].items():
    print(key, val)
```

In this way, the objects inside the sub-object will be printed

outcome:

```
tnType None
tnCode None
postedDt None
amt None
tranDesc1 None
```

The easy way to insert the dictionary values ​​into a new list is like this:

```
values_list = []

for item in my_test_data:
    for key, val in item.items():
        values_list.append(val)
```

outcome:

```
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: "*access key with parameter 0*" It's normally called the **list index**. In this case, you are accessing the list item at index 0.

Comment: i changed I couldn't remember what to call it exactly

Answer (score 1):

look
you have some dictonary in your list right?

so in my code when you use `for data in my_datas` you create a loop for every item in your list

then when you use `for items in data.items()` every dictionary in your list you have run this code and you get the items and values!

i hope my explain was a good explain (my english level is bad sorry!)

```
my_datas = [
        {
            'tnType': None,
            'tnCode': None,
            'postedDt': None,
            'amt': None, 'tranDesc1': None
        }
    ]


for data in my_datas:
    for item in data.items():
        print(item)
```

the output :

```
('tnType', None)
('tnCode', None)   
('postedDt', None) 
('amt', None)      
('tranDesc1', None)
```

Comment: This code looks good, but how does it answer the question? Please [edit] to add an explanation -- could be as little as one or two sentences. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [answer] if you want tips.

Comment: I want to be able to read the values of "None" and store all those None in another list. How can I get those values of None for each row?

Comment: Do you want the values (all of which are `None` at the moment in a list, or do you want the keys in a list where the value associated with the key is `None`? for eample a list like `["tnType", "tnCode", ...]`

Comment: I need all the values stored in a list and counted.  I think I have code to that that now.  for key, val in my_test_data[0].items(): print(val).  This will do it